# band-pass filter poles and zeroes of even function

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

let $ \omega_H>\omega_L>0$ be frequencies.
I need to create an LTI non ideal band-pass filter so that$$ Y\left(s\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \omega_{L}<\left|\omega\right|<\omega_{H}\\
0 & else
\end{cases} $$
The transfer function must be :

- Causal
- BIBO stable
- Rational
- Has a real valued impulse response.
- For every constant input $x(t)=c\Rightarrow y(x(t))=0 $
- Has minimal amount of poles and zeroes.

I'm not really sure how to approach all the details.

Because it is causal, we will have a right side ROC.

Because it is rational it means $ H\left(s\right)=\frac{\sum\limits _{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{i}s^{i}}{\sum\limits _{i=1}^{n}\beta_{i}s^{i}} $

Bibo stable means that the $ j\omega $ axis is included in the ROC.

Because it resets every constant, we know that it involves differentiating in the time domain, so $ H(s)=sX(s)$.

My problem is with the real valued impulse response.
If $ h(t) $ is real valued then it's Laplace transform $ H(s) $ is an even function.
But because $ H(s) $ is even and we have poles in $ \omega_L $ and $\omega_H$ it means we basically should have poles in $ -\omega_L$ and $-\omega_H$.
The system is also $ 0 $ for every constant, so $ s=0 $ should be a zero of the transform, but in order to keep it an even function we must square it.

In the end my function looks like : $$ H\left(s\right)=\frac{s^{2}}{\left(s+\omega_{L}\right)\left(s+\omega_{H}\right)\left(s-\omega_{L}\right)\left(s-\omega_{H}\right)} $$

However this function contradicts the BIBO property since the ROC is jut right of $\omega_H$ and hence we don't include $j\omega $.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: No such thing exists.

Comment: Mind explaining why? Seems odd we are asked to design such a system if it's impossible, perhaps I just didn't phrase the question right.

Comment: The question is probably better suited to dsp.stackexchange.com. An ideal filter is unrealisable because it is non causal.